# Is there any differences between Pyomo Set and Python set?

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, pyomo

First time pyomo user here.

Is there any difference between declaring sets in an optimization model as

```
model.A = Set(initialize = list_values)
```

and using a built in python set like this one?

```
A = set(list_values)
```

Are there any advantages of one over the other?

Answer (score 0):

First you can call the model variables, sets, parameters in the constraint rules via:

```
def some_constraint_rule(model):
    return model.some_set
```

So you cant do something like this via python sets because the model you input in the constraint rule does not have your python set.

Second you cannot index python sets (so far I know, therefore u need a dict??), but with pyomo sets, u can do much more stuff eg.:

```
m.t = pyomo.Set(
    within=m.index,
    initialize=something,
    ordered=True,
    doc='some documentation for your set?')
```